# how to use $.each in json?

Tags: jquery

Can anyone expalin me about $.each() ?

Comment: Oh look there is documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ Maybe you want to elaborate on what you mean with *$.each in json*.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the following array object:

```
var data = [ { 'id': '1', 'name': 'foo' }, { 'id': 1, 'name': 'bar' } ];
```

you can loop through its elements:

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
    // this will be executed for each element of the array and here
    // you can use value.id and value.name which are the two properties
    // defined for each object in the array
});
```

But usually this JSON comes from the server in response to an [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request. So in the success callback of this request you could loop through the array elements returned by the server:

```
$.getJSON('/foo.cgi', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
        alert(value.name);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Need more than this one ?](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

[Maybe see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863166/practical-uses-for-jquerys-each-method-for-a-presentation)